# Troubles with: sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql

I developed a simple PHP/MySQL app which works well on my localhost using MAMP PRO 4.1.

The issue is when I moved my app to VPS managed by ServerPilot (basically classic LAMP stack).

I'm getting this error from sql:

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
>   nonaggregated column 'voluum_optimizer.c.campaign_name' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

After Googling I managed to suppress it by running the following code before my main query:

```
SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

But this is probably a "hack" and not the right way to do things.

I wonder how I should write my queries as I didn't have this problem for years, but probably from some new versions of MySQL some stuff changed and now I need to change all my apps until I suppress these errors.

Any guide or tips would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

with any new version of MySQL, MySQL more and more "SQL"

Yes, MySQL allow many hints, which most of other databases reject with errors.

it is and:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY column
```

and 
hidden datatype conversion, like:

```
SELECT xxx FROM table WHERE VARCHAR = INT
```

but You have only one true choice - start change code for proper form

because if in case of hidden type conversion, You are just slowdown server (sometime dramatically), in case of suppress

```
sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

You never can be sure - what information fetched?
And what if it official (government required) report? and You fetch wrong, not current address? Or You send package from Your internet store to wrong (outdate) address?